# Nginx URL wise redirect

Tags: nginx

I have a some case to map in nginx

1. for /  it take from the /var/www/html/cont
2. for /content/*  it take form the var/www/html/cont
3. if it is not / and not /content/*
   the it should take from /var/www/html/web

i am stucking in case 3

Here is my config

```
    location / {
                 root /var/www/html/cont;
                 if (!-e $request_filename){
                     rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
                 }
                 # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
             }
   location /content {
                 root /var/www/html/cont;
                 if (!-e $request_filename){
                     rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
                 }
                 # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
             }
```

Any help appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: If case 1 means only `/` then use `location = /` and use `location /` for case 3.

Comment: but in case 1 and case 3 root is different @RichardSmith

Comment: Use `location / { root /var/www/html/web; }` for case 3.

Answer (score 0):

Set `root` for `server {}` context as `root /var/www/html/web;`

then

```
location / {
    root /var/www/html/cont;
    # your other directives
}

location /content {
    root /var/www/html/cont;
    # your other directives
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution which works perfectly in as per my use case.

```
    location / {
                 if ($request_uri = "/") {
                     set $custom_root /var/www/html/cont;
                 }
    
                 if ($request_uri != "/") {
                     set $custom_root /var/www/html/web;
                 }
    
                 root $custom_root;
    
                 if (!-e $request_filename) {
                     rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
                 }
                 # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
             }

location /content {
            root /var/www/html/cont;
            if (!-e $request_filename) {
                 rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
             }
    }
```